# How to generate QPSK signal in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, communication

I am trying to generate the QPSK signal in MATLAB with average transmit power of 1. I had got certain links that uses inbuilt `pskmod` function in MATLAB, but it do not include average transmit power of 1.

This is the code I use to generate the QPSK signal:

```
Mod = 4;
N = 256;
x_n = randi([0 Mod-1],N,1);

s_n = pskmod(x_n,Mod,pi/Mod);
```

I don't know where the signal constellation power factors in.

Comment: What prevents you from scaling the output of `pskmod` to get the desired average transmit power?

Comment: Thanks sir for your reply. I used the following command to generate the QPSK signal: Here Mod = 4, N = 256 .                                                                                                                                                                                                         
x_n = randi([0 Mod-1],N,1); 
s_n = pskmod(x_n,Mod,pi/Mod);                                                                                             But I didnt find Power term in this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be observed from the various sample graphs in [`pskmod` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/pskmod.html), the generated symbols have a magnitude of 1. So unless you are using a different basis function than the typical sine/cosine, it should already be providing you with a signal with an average transmit power of 1.

That said, if you would like a different average power simply scale the output of `pskmod` with the square-root of the desired average power as follows:

```
Mod = 4;
N = 256;
x_n = randi([0 Mod-1],N,1);

P = 2; % Set desired constellation power
s_n = sqrt(P) * pskmod(x_n,Mod,pi/Mod);
```

Comment: Understood it completely. Thanks a lot sir for your detailed answer.